# How to show table data in ng-bootstrap in angular 8

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular8

I am trying to show multiple table data in a table So i am declared each variable.If i click table 1 button i want to show tabledatas1 array data same like If i click table 2 button i want to show tabledatas2 array data same like for table 3 button. But i do not how to assign the array to table data service.If you see my stackblitz you can easily understand.Please help to find the solution.

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yz5ch9-xmdqv8?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-complete.ts

table-complete.html:

```
<div class="col-4">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="forTableData1()">Table 1</button>
</div>
   <div class="col-4">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="forTableData2()">Table 2</button>
</div>
   <div class="col-4">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="forTableData3()">Table 3</button>
</div> 
</div>
```

table-complete.ts:

```
 forTableData1(){
    this.service.tabledataGet(this.tabledatas1);
 }
 forTableData2(){
    this.service.tabledataGet(this.tabledatas2);
 }
 forTableData3(){
    this.service.tabledataGet(this.tabledatas3);
 }
```

Comment: Arrays tabledatas1, tabledatas2, tabledatas3 are identical in your example, you won't notice the change

Comment: I think your problem is that you're ngFor-ing through countries but your service.tabledataGet(data), only sets this.tabledata=data and nothing else. tabledata and countries don't connect. Which is why it gives you "Error: countries is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

create a global variable called `selectedData`

```js
selectedData: Array<any> = [];
```

iterate on `selectedData` template

```html
    <tr *ngFor="let country of selectedData">
      <th scope="row">{{ country.id }}</th>
      <td>
        <img [src]="'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/' + country.flag" class="mr-2" style="width: 20px">
        <ngb-highlight [result]="country.name" [term]="service.searchTerm"></ngb-highlight>
      </td>
      <td><ngb-highlight [result]="country.area | number" [term]="service.searchTerm"></ngb-highlight></td>
      <td><ngb-highlight [result]="country.population | number" [term]="service.searchTerm"></ngb-highlight></td>
    </tr>
```

on clicking of buttons set each country array to `selectedData`

```js
  forTableData1(){
    // Rest of the method
    this.selectedData = this.tabledatas1;
  }
  forTableData2(){
     // Rest of the method
     this.selectedData = this.tabledatas2;
  }
  forTableData3(){
    // Rest of the method
    this.selectedData = this.tabledatas3; 
  }
```

Comment: If i use your concept table sorting and pagination will not work